# Azure NODE_PATH environment variable doesn't have any effect

Tags: node.js, azure, environment-variables

I have a NodeJS project deployed to Azure with some project-wide modules like config.

```
├── bin
│    └── start
├── config
│    └── index.js
└── web.config
```

Locally I start my app with `npm start` which works OK on Windows.

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "SET NODE_PATH=.& node bin/start"
}
```

On Azure I haven't found a way to run scripts from `package.json`, thus I altered `web.config` to run `node bin/start`.

NODE_PATH env variable is set via "Application settings" -> "App settings" and is echoed correctly. However, it doesn't have any effect.

`bin/start` file outputs env vars and error message `Start "production" - "." - "Cannot find module 'config'"`:

```
var http = require('http');
var util = require('util');
var nconf = require('nconf');

nconf.argv()
     .env();

var configMsg = 'default msg';
try {
    var config = require('config');
    if(config) {
        configMsg = 'WOOT!';
    }
} catch (e) {
    configMsg = e.message;
}

http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });

  res.end(
    util.format(
        'Start "%s" - "%s" - "%s"',
        nconf.get('NODE_ENV'),
        nconf.get('NODE_PATH'),
        configMsg
    )
  );
}).listen(process.env.PORT);
```

How can I make Azure understand NODE_PATH ?

Or alternatively, how can I tell Azure to run my app with npm script like `npm start` ?

Answer (score 1):

As the `scripts` in `package.json` is used for `npm` cli, like `npm start` in your project to run the application. However, node.js applications on Azure Web Apps are hosted by iisnode, which will bypass the `packages.json` file.

You can consider the following workarounds:

- Move your custom module (`config` folder here) into `node_modules` folder in your root directory. When you use `require('config')`, the process will search the module '`config`' in `node_modules` folder
- Keep the architecture of your application, modify the script code where you need to involve your custom module, e.g `var config = require('../config');` to involve the relative path of your module

Comment: Thank's for the answer! Unfortunately these workarounds are not suitable for me. 1) `node_modules` is excluded from git and project structure is settled; 2) `require('../config')` becomes `require('../../../../config')` or `models = require('../../models')`, etc. First option seems to be least painful of two. If `iisnode` bypasses `packages.json` and ignores npm, how does it install dependencies? Why does it ignore env variables?

Comment: the command `npm install` is ran by deployment task but iisnode, you can refer to https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Deployment-hooks for this info.

Comment: Thanks for the link! Will look into it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do npm start in Azure web apps, npm start actually looks for package.json file and runs the script thus specified against it with the configurations in package.json file, while in Azure web apps - the azure platform looks for the presence of app.js or server.js file in root and does the `node <server.js>` command on it.

I find this article very interesting when it comes to understanding of how azure runs your nodejs app http://blogs.msdn.com/b/silverlining/archive/2012/06/14/windows-azure-websites-node-js.aspx.

If you don't want to ship the entire node_modules folder to the web app, than you must have a package.json file with you and the azure will run the npm for your web app.

Comment: I actually NEED to be able to run any scripts specified in `package.json`, in this case script will help me to specify proper env vars for my app. I know that in `web.config` startup file may be changed to anything, in my case `node bin/www`.